# Relative address of main bundle from an NSManagedDocument

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, css, uiwebview

1. I have an NSManagedDocument that has a string attribute composed of a small amount of html which will be used by a `UIWebView`. I also have a style sheet saved in my main bundle that I'm trying to give the relative path to, from the html. How would I go about that? I tried `href="../MyApp.app/style.css"`, under the assumption that the html would be in the NSDocumentDirectory, but that didn't seem to work.
2. Is it possible to load some html in `UIWebView`, then separately load a css (that isn't linked to from the html) and apply it to the html?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is construct a self-contained html string. In other words, load the html, then load the style data from inside the bundle using the usual `[NSBundle mainBundle]` foo, and then combine them by inserting a `<style>` tag into the `<head>` of the html in the usual way.